# Software performance

Tags: sampling

I have a software that I need to test for performance. I automated it but wanted to know how many times do I need to run it? It takes 20 mins to complete a full test and I have days if required.

Comment: Thank you for the question, but it is not clear what you testing?  Are you comparing software?  Are you calculating the variance for multiple runs of the same software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to identify it in your test plan. This probably depend on the schedule of the project itself. This is important since it will determine the error rate of the software performance.